# Don't repeat COLUMN_GET in MariaDB dynamic columns WHERE clause

Tags: mariadb

I have a MariaDB query like this:

```
select id, column_get(params, 'Variant' as char) as variant 
from runs 
where column_get(params, 'Variant' as char) in ('Whatever', 'Wherever');
```

Is there a way to not have to repeat the whole `column_get()` bit twice?

*Edit*: Fixed tautological example.

Comment: If so use WITH clause. But it may be less effective. Moreover, I think the expression is written twice, but calculated once. So if you solve your task you will save a lot of bytes only.

Comment: Yeah I'm not worried about the calculation - seems to be plenty fast enough. Just the repetitiveness. Can you explain the `WITH` clause? I can't see how it would help.

Comment: `WITH cte AS (select id, column_get(params, 'Variant' as char) as variant 
from runs) SELECT * FROM cte WHERE variant IN ('Whatever', 'Wherever');`

Comment: Ah I see. Will that have the same performance characteristics?

Comment: I don't know (not use MariaDB at all) - test it.

Comment: I ran both queries with `ANALYZE FORMAT=JSON` and they appear to give identical results. Good enough for me.

Comment: `they appear to give identical results` They must give identical results... but you were interested in performance - have you tested it? If there is a difference, it can be detected only on a huge data array...

Comment: I mean identical results from `ANALZE`. I haven't tested on a huge data set.